# Row wise subtraction based on multiple criteria (columns) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
date      locid month       price
11/2/2017   17  11/1/2017   -0.0025
11/2/2017   17  12/1/2017   0
11/2/2017   105 11/1/2017   -0.895
11/2/2017   105 12/1/2017   -1
11/3/2017   17  11/1/2017   -0.0025
11/3/2017   17  12/1/2017   0.01
11/3/2017   105 11/1/2017   -0.895
11/3/2017   105 12/1/2017   -1.01
```

I would like to return a result that shows the difference in prices, at each locid, for each month, on each date.  The result would only have four rows:

```
date        month       price
11/2/2017   11/1/2017   0.8925
11/2/2017   12/1/2017   1
11/3/2017   11/1/2017   0.8925
11/3/2017   12/1/2017   1.02
```

I've obtained the result only with the following line:

```
df.loc[df['locid']==17].price - df.loc[df['locid']==105].price
```

However, I don't think this is a robust solution. Prior to sorting the df.date column, my result contained eight rows. Also, i'm not sure that python/pandas is matching the df.months, I think they just may happen to be in the right order.

I would like to know how to:

1) **ensure i am subtracting in the right order (in this case i want locid 17-105), what if they were in the opposite order in my data**?  What if there were three locids and i wanted to see only two?

2) ensure locid 17-105 is date==11/2/2017 and month==11/1/2017.  IE date and month have to match, before subtracting

3) if the data was pivoted first, how to do the subtraction

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` with `diff` , then inner `concat` back to original df

```
df1=df.drop(['locid','price'],axis = 1)
df2=df.groupby(['date','month']).price.diff().dropna().abs()
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1 ,join ='inner' )
Out[552]: 
        date      month   price
2  11/2/2017  11/1/2017  0.8925
3  11/2/2017  12/1/2017  1.0000
6  11/3/2017  11/1/2017  0.8925
7  11/3/2017  12/1/2017  1.0200
```

Comment: Thanks - what if I want to do locid 105-17.  It looks like you may have achieved the result I wanted in part by using abs() (without abs your code returns wrong sign).  I care about the sign in this case though.  Depending on what I am looking at I may want to see if this is positive or negative.  So how would you specify which locid to subtract from which locid?